# How to solve the view broken when the personal hotspot is on in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uitabbarcontroller, hotspot

I create the view programmatically for `UITabBarController`.

In **`ViewController.m`**

```
@interface ViewController ()
{   
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    MainViewController *mainView;
    GroupViewController *grpView;
}

-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];

    [self initControl];
    return self;
}


-(void)initControl
{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSLog(@"ViewController - viewDidLoad");
    self.mainView=[[MainViewController alloc] init];
    self.grpView=[[GroupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GroupViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.meView=[[MeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    

    
    UITabBarItem *tempItem=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Device", @"Device") image:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"device1"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] tag:1];
    tempItem.selectedImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"device"];
    mainView.tabBarItem=tempItem;
    tempItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0, -0.0, 0);
    

    tempItem=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Group", @"Group") image:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"group1"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] tag:2];
    tempItem.selectedImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"group1"];
    grpView.tabBarItem=tempItem;
    tempItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0, -0.0, 0);
    
    self.tabBarController= [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *controllers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
    
    [controllers addObject:self.mainView];
    [controllers addObject:self.grpView];
    
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers =controllers;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
}
```

It is work fine when the personal hotspot is off.

[image]

When I turn on the Hotspot and somebody connect to the iPhone , and than open the App. The `view` is out of the screen like the following screen shot **when the personal hotspot is on**.

[image]

How to solve the problem when the personal hotspot is turn on?

Comment: Using proper constraints easily resolves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**check this**

add observer for  status bar changed the length:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(StatusbarspaceHide:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

**action when status bar changed :**

```
-(void)StatusbarspaceHide:(NSNotificationCenter *)notification{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
        // CGRect windowFrame = ((UINavigationController *)((UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController).viewControllers[0]).view.frame;
        CGRect windowFrame = self.view.frame;

        if (self.view.frame.origin.y > 20) {
            windowFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 20 ;// old status bar frame is 20
        }
        self.view.frame = windowFrame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: I have try , but it did not receive any notification.

Comment: its working for me fine... what happened did u checked with breakpoints